# What's the difference (in FXML) between layout.Pane and control.Control?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to learn how to create a UI.  What I am currently experimenting with is a main screen on the left to house the current information for the user to see; and an Accordion on the right, for the user to select items which determine what is shown in the main screen.  I am using Scene Builder to help me as I learn.  When I drag a TitledPane (not empty) into my Accordion, it places an AnchorPane in there.  This, unless I misunderstand something, does not allow for a list of selectable items in that TitledPane larger than the current height of the TitledPane.  So I added another TitledPane (empty) into my Accordion, and then added a ScrollPane (not empty) to it.  This again added an AnchorPane inside of the ScrollPane.

This is what my fxml document currently looks like (after the versioning, encoding and imports):

```
<VBox fx:id="testPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testfxml.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <MenuBar>
            <menus>
            <Menu text="File">
                <items>
                    <MenuItem fx:id="1" text="1" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="2" text="2" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="3" text="3" />
                </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.75" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="800">
        <items>
            <StackPane fx:id="mainscreen" />
            <Accordion fx:id="test">
                <panes>
                    <TitledPane text="Test1">
                        <content>
                            <AnchorPane fx:id="test1" />
                        </content>
                    </TitledPane>
                    <TitledPane text="Test2">
                       <content>
                          <ScrollPane>
                             <content>
                               <AnchorPane/>
                             </content>
                          </ScrollPane>
                       </content>
                    </TitledPane>          
                </panes>
            </Accordion>
        </items>
    </SplitPane>
</children>
```

When I look at the api for javafx (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api),  AnchorPane shows this:

Class AnchorPane

```
java.lang.Object
   javafx.scene.Node
      javafx.scene.Parent
         javafx.scene.layout.Region
            javafx.scene.layout.Pane
               javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
```

While ScrollPane shows this:

Class ScrollPane

```
java.lang.Object
   javafx.scene.Node
      javafx.scene.Parent
         javafx.scene.layout.Region
            javafx.scene.control.Control
               javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane
```

I'm assuming the formatting, which to me implies inheritance, is significant.  I noticed that down through "javafx.scene.layout.Region" is identical, but that they differ after that.  One goes to layout.Pane, the other to control.Control.

I've read through the descriptions on the api and, perhaps because of my obvious lack of experience with coding, it didn't quite make sense to me - perhaps I'm trying to use one of them incorrectly?

What's the difference?  Is an AnchorPane required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything you like as the content of a `TitledPane`. SceneBuilder (which seems unduly fond of `AnchorPane`s, for some reason) puts an `AnchorPane` as the default content; however you can remove it, or just choose "TitledPane (empty)" and add your own content. For example, you can remove the `AnchorPane` (or start with an empty `TitledPane`) and drag a `ScrollPane` there instead.

It actually sounds like you really need a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) as the content of your `TitledPane`. A `ListView` comes already equipped with as-needed scroll bar functionality.

To answer your actual question, the API documentation is indeed indicating the inheritance hierarchy.

JavaFX (like most UI libraries) defines a rich inheritance structure. `Parent` is the superclass of anything in the scene graph that contains other `Node`s. The vast majority of classes that subclass `Parent` also subclass `Region`, which represents something that takes up a particular space in the layout. (The exceptions are `Group`, which behaves somewhat differently with respect to layout, and `WebView`, which probably should be a subclass of `Control`, but isn't...).

`Control` and `Pane` are both subclasses of `Region` (and hence of `Parent`). `Pane` represents a "container": something that is merely designed to hold other `Node`s and manage their layout. `AnchorPane` is a subclass of `Pane`. `Control`, by contrast, represents a UI "widget" (something with which the user directly interacts), so `Label`, `Button`, `ComboBox`, etc, are all subclasses of `Control`.

Some controls are actually quite complex, and contain other `Node`s. `ScrollPane` is an example of a control, because the user can interact with it (via its scroll bars); it also contains another `Node`, called its "content". In the same way that you can use any `Node` as the content for the `TitledPane`, you can use any node as the content for the `ScrollPane`. The `ScrollPane`'s `content` is the node the user views and moves around via the `ScrollPane`'s scroll bars. Again, you can use any `Node` as the `ScrollPane`'s content; SceneBuilder just chooses an `AnchorPane` as the default (for no real reason other than it has to use something).

Comment: I would vote it up, but I'm new and not allowed yet.  :-)  Very informative and helpful answer.

Comment: You can mark it as correct if it answers the question, regardless of reputation.